# setViewController with Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying go from one view controller to another using a navigation menu. My problem is it will access the code from AddNewHomeTableViewController, but will not access my view controller from the storyboard. Below is how I access the code:

```
AddNewHomeTableViewController *controller = [[AddNewHomeTableViewController alloc] init];
[weakSelf setViewControllers:@[controller] animated:YES];
```

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't access (or create as you do in your code) a view controller in a storyboard with alloc init. You use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

```
AddNewHomeTableViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddHome"]; //be sure the identifier you use here is the same one you define in the storyboard
```